What (if any) pre-breathes were "attempted" on the ISS, and why?
CNN's August 19, 2024 SpaceX is about to send four people on a wild — and risky — mission into the radiation belts. Here’s what to know includes:

Almost immediately after reaching space, the Polaris Dawn crew will begin a “pre-breathe” process to prepare for the spacewalk. It’s akin to what scuba divers do to avoid decompression sickness, otherwise known as “the bends.” The crewmates must purge nitrogen from their blood so that when the Dragon capsule is depressurized and exposed to the vacuum of space, the gas doesn’t form bubbles in their bloodstream — a potentially lethal condition.
“We don’t have an airlock on this mission,” Gillis told CNN, referring to the areas on board the International Space Station (ISS) that serve as special decompression chambers for astronauts heading out for a spacewalk. Polaris Dawn will instead take “a really novel and different approach” to the pre-breathing process that involves “slowly decreasing cabin pressure and raising oxygen concentration.”
Unlike any pre-breathe attempted on the International Space Station, the process will take roughly 45 hours — nearly two days, said Gillis, who works as a lead space operations engineer at SpaceX and trained the Inspiration4 crew for their mission.

The ISS DOES have an airlock, so I'd like to ask:
Question: What (if any) pre-breathes were "attempted" on the ISS, and why?

companion question (related but different) Why will the Polaris Dawn "pre-breathe" be so long (45 hours) and gradual? What are the proposed advantages over a short one?

There is always a prebreathe prior to an EVA from the US side of the ISS.

Prior to each EVA, an oxygen
prebreathe is conducted to prevent
the crew from getting the bends
after depressurization of the
airlock (i.e., when the absolute
suit pressure drops to 222 mm Hg
[4.3 psi]). This is the same DCS
that ascending scuba divers as
well as aviators at high altitudes
must also prevent. Breathing
100% oxygen forces nitrogen to
migrate out of tissues and is exhaled.
If done for long enough, the chances
are greatly reduced that these gases
will create harmful bubbles that
can lodge in joints or travel in the bloodstream to critical organs,
resulting in pain, severe medical issues, and even death.
Multiple prebreathe protocols have
been available and used on the Space
Shuttle and the ISS. The various
protocols can involve oxygen masks,
exercise in the suit or on a bicycle
machine, reduction in cabin pressure
to 528 mm Hg (10.2 psi) (~equivalent
to 3 km [10,000 ft] altitude) for a
period of time, and/or prebreathe in
the spacesuit. Prebreathe methods
have evolved to incorporate
reductions in crew day length and
reduced complexity. For example,
at one point, prebreathe (Figure 23)
involved having the EVA crew
sleep in the Joint Airlock overnight
at a reduced cabin pressure; however,
this had its pitfalls. In addition to
sequestering the extravehicular
crew members from their crewmates
and the toilet, certain failures such
as a fire alarm on the ISS will cause
a repress of the airlock and will
interrupt the prebreathe process.
This can be frustrating when the
alarm is false, as has happened in
the past, since any interruptions in
prebreathe protocol require strict
penalties to “buy back” the time.
Depending on the situation, the crew
might have to breathe pure oxygen
for twice the number of minutes than
was the interruption.

Source: ISS: Operating a Outpost Chapter 17
There's a paper "EVA and Human Physiology" by Svensson, Vogt, and Herber that goes into the rationale for the prebreathes a bit more. I don't find that paper on the internet though.

Pure oxygen breathing, prebreathing, immediately before the decompression reduces the risk (of "bends"). By this method the tissue nitrogen is eliminated faster because the pure oxygen in the inhaled gas replaces the nitrogen in the lung. As a result a maximum diffusion gradient for the elimination of nitrogen from organism is established...

The reason for all the different protocols is an attempt to strike a balance between an effective/safe prebreathe and the inconvenience to the EVA crewmembers. One of the Shuttle protocols was a 4 hour prebreathe in the suit. Not how a crewperson wants to spend their time in orbit.
Source: Shuttle Environmental Control and Life Support Training Manual page 2-28.
For EVA-heavy Shuttle missions they would depress to 10.2 psi a day before the first EVA and stay there until the EVAs were done. For example, on STS-088 they did the 10.2 depress 19 hours into the mission and stayed there until 7 days, 20 hours into the mission (with a brief excursion back up to 14.7 psia to ingress the Functional Cargo Block ISS module).


Source: STS-088 Flight Plan & fond memories

I remember when they did the campouts in the Quest airlock. Of course they weren't in the crew lock (the skinny part with the hatch) but in the larger equipment lock. The article mentions problems caused by fire alarms, but I seem to remember that in the morning they were allowed to leave the airlock to have breakfast and use the toilet, followed by an hour breathing 100% oxygen or something like that before they suited up.

@StevePemberton agreed, that last hour probably included the "buyback" mentioned in the article, for the time spent having breakfast.

Wow, I can't imagine executing off a paper timeline! I feel spoiled from having OPTIMIS with linked procedures and resource tracking.

@Doresoom when I started working in the shuttle program we didn't even have desktop PCs.

There was also a project for determining effectiveness of prebreathe by monitoring for formation of nitrogen bubbles (at sizes too small to cause DCS) with an intent of finding the minimum required prebreathe time.

"There is always a prebreathe prior to an EVA from the *US side *of the ISS."  The Ruskies don't prebreathe?

@RonJohn I simply don't know.

Inconceivable!!
